# How to access a useState globally?

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a ecommerce site and I have a feature to show cart Items number  in nav bar. This nav bar is common for all page so it is in a different file. In the navbar I made the carticon into a react hook and used usestate to get and show cart number.

```
const CartNumber = () =>{
    const [cartNumber, setCartNumber] = React.useState(0);
    async function getCartN(){
      var d = await getCartItem();
      setCartNumber(d.cartData.length);
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        getCartN();
    }, cartNumber);
  return <NavLink to="/cart">
  <MdOutlineShoppingCart className="cart-icon cart-icons" />
  <span id="cart-count">{cartNumber}</span>
</NavLink>
}
```

Here if I use setCartNumber then the cart number would also update. But the problem is I want to call this outside this file since add to cart button is on another page. So how can I make this setCartNumber globally accesible.

Comment: You should use [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: use React Context or React-Redux for this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You sould use a context api: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Or a library like redux, to be able to manage the global state of your app: https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this goal, you have to use Redux or Context API.
By using one of them, you can use states globally and update them easily.

Answer (score 0):

In React two states one is local and the second is global.
In Redux state management library handle both states. I highly recommended you should learn the Functional Programming concept and the second thing you learn is redux.
I already face this problem so Mosh instructor resolves my problem and clear the whole concept of redux.
I highly recommend you should see the Mosh redux series.
Context API is not preferred especially in big projects.